# I'm doing "userinfo" command and idk what I must write to get mentioned meber highestRole in embeds

Tags: discord.js

As in Title.
I tried "user.highestRole" but when I (in Discord) use command with mentioned other user, in highestRole field i see my rank.

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}user`){
   let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

   let userInfo = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor(user.tag, user.avatarURL)
      .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL)
      .setFooter("Informacje Użytkownika")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#1d1dbb")
      .addField("Nick:", user.username)
      .addField("Najwyższa ranga:", user.highestRole)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}user`){
  let user = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0] ) || message.author)

   let userInfo = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor(user.tag, user.avatarURL)
      .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL)
      .setFooter("Informacje Użytkownika")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#1d1dbb")
      .addField("Nick:", user.username)
      .addField("Najwyższa ranga:", user.highestRole)
```

Because you need to get it as guild member